# GCP workload identity federation with Azure

Tags: .net, azure, google-cloud-platform, identity, federation

I have an azure function written in c# that publishes messages to gcp pubsub topic. It works fine with credential file we received from gcp , but now due to some security we would like to use identity federation and use short-lived tokens generated by our AAD tenant to authenticate the calls. I have the code that generates the access-token in place

```
    public async Task<string> GetToken()
{
    var credential = _userAssignedClientId == null
        ? new DefaultAzureCredential()
        : new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
            { ManagedIdentityClientId = _userAssignedClientId });

    var accessToken =
        await credential.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(new[]
            { _resourceUri }));
    return accessToken.Token;
}
```

and here is the code that we were using for the credential

```
            var builder = new PublisherClientBuilder
        {
            JsonCredentials = _credentials,
            TopicName = TopicName.FromProjectTopic(_projectId, _topicId)
        };
        
        var publisher = await builder.BuildAsync();
```

The question is , there is no obvious way to introduce the access token to gcp .net client, it only receives credential which is different from the access token, and the credential generated by `DefaultAzureCredential` also can not be used. The question is how to use the generated access_token to authenticate my publisher to gcp. The gcp side is also configured to trust the AAD app.

Answer (score 2):

> The question is how to use the generated access_token to authenticate my publisher to gcp

If you have an access_token that is valid for Google Cloud, then you can do as follows:

```cs
var builder = new PublisherClientBuilder
{
    GoogleCredential = Google.Apis.Auth.GoogleCredential.FromAccessToken(accessToken);
    TopicName = TopicName.FromProjectTopic(_projectId, _topicId);
};
```

Note that I've said "if you have an access_token that is valid for Google Cloud" because I'm not familiar with the `DefaultAzureCredential` method or with the type of credential it returns.

Now, regardless of that, starting at v1.58.0 the [Google.Apis.Auth](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Auth/1.58.0) library, which is the Google owned and recommended .NET Auth library for Google, supports Workload Identity Federation, including for Azure.

If you follow [Configure workload identity federation with Azure](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation-with-other-clouds#azure) then your code only needs to look like this (i.e. specify no credential):

```cs
var builder = new PublisherClientBuilder
{
    TopicName = TopicName.FromProjectTopic(_projectId, _topicId);
};
```

A `PublisherClient` built like this will use the configured workload identity federation credential that GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is referencing (from the documentation above) and will generate and refresh access tokens as needed.

If you run into any issues, feel free to create and issue in https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client

Comment: Thanks , Tried your solution but received an error and created an issue for it : https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/2324